# How do I make it so my table doesn't format "wrong" in HTML?

Tags: html

I want to make a table look like

[image: this]

but when I try to code it, I always seem to get it to look like

[image: this]

```html
    <html>
    
        <head>
        </head>
        
        <body>
        <table border="1" width="50%" height="50%" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
            <tr>
            <td colspan="2"></td>
            </tr>
            
            <tr>
            <td rowspan="2"></td>
            <td></td>
            </tr>
            
            <tr>
            <td rowspan="2"></td>
            </tr>
            
            <tr>
            <td></td>
            </tr>
            
        </table>
        </body>
        
    </html>
```

Comment: That doesn't look like a very likely representation of a data structure. What data do you have for that? Or are you abusing tables for layout? We have CSS now, with tools much better suited for this kind of layout.

Comment: I’m very new to this and is just starting to learn the basics. 
Right now I’m learning about tables and how they can be used, and the table I want basically is “practice” for how to use tables.

Comment: If you're going in trying to create weird **layouts** using tables, then you aren't learning how to use tables any more than levering the top of a can of paint with a screwdriver is learning how to use a screwdriver.

Comment: It’s an “assignment”  we got from our teacher to practice what we had learnt about tables. However as you’ve said it might be outdated and an inefficient way to do it nowadays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem with that layout is that the heights will cause it to collapse down. If define heights it will look correct. So you had the right concept, you are just missing heights/content to make it look correct.

```css
table, td {
  width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #595959;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50%;
}

td[rowspan="2"] {
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2">2</td>
            <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2">4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>5</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Be better to use a [CSS Grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid) instead of a table to get that layout

```css
.parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-column-gap: 0px;
  grid-row-gap: 0px;
}
.parent > div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  min-height: 50px;
}

.div1 {
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 3;
}

.div2 {
  grid-area: 2 / 1 / 4 / 2;
}

.div3 {
  grid-area: 2 / 2 / 3 / 3;
}

.div4 {
  grid-area: 3 / 2 / 5 / 3;
}

.div5 {
  grid-area: 4 / 1 / 5 / 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="div1">1</div>
  <div class="div2">2</div>
  <div class="div3">3</div>
  <div class="div4">4</div>
  <div class="div5">5</div>
</div>
```